# Laravel Eloquent db search based on a list of keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a list of keys and I am currently iterating over the list of keys and searching the db based on the individual key in the list of keys

```
        $keys = $collection->keys();
        foreach($keys as $key){
            $found = SampleCV::where('job_title', $key)->get();
            if($found != '[]')
            {
                $foundJobTitle = $found;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to do the search based off using the keys and not have to iterate through each key?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries use whereIn?

Comment: @MateuszSip, $test =  SampleCV::whereIn('job_title', $keys)->get();
        Log::Debug($test); gives me an empty array

Comment: are you sure that $keys is a valid array in this context?

Comment: @MateuszSip, yes I am.

Comment: @MateuszSip, thanks I figured out how to get it to work